# Using a time delay in javascript

Tags: javascript

So if I had some code, and I wanted to print this certain variable every 1 second (or any number, but constantly updating) how would I do that? I need a variable to be printed onto the page every 1 second, and I may need to do similar things with other variables later, but I'm just not sure how I would do this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set interval can do this. If you want to delay it for one time only, use setTimeout. See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
let SECOND = 1000;
let variableToChange = 0;

setInterval(function(){
   variableToChange++;
}, SECOND)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const callbackFunction = function () { /*do something*/ };    
setInterval( callbackFunction, 1000); //callbackFunction is invoked every 1000ms (1s).
```

Comment: Add some details which show that it is a helpful statement in your answer.